# Hibernate Like Restriction

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have a table in which books are saved. In another table there are references saved as a string (sounds stupid, was not my idea). The data roughly looks like this:

```
Book: Fairytales
Reference: Fairytales, p. 153
```

Now, I want the book given a reference. Usually I would use this:

```
Restrictions.like("name", reference, Matchmode.START);
```

But this does not work, since it gives me all the books where the names start with the reference, but I need the restriction to be the other way around. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by other way around exactly, required output.

Comment: I need all books where the title is the start of the given reference: reference.startsWith(title). The criteria restriction gives me title.startWith(reference)

Comment: Still incomplete information, why can't you update question with relevant code; how reference, title, criteria, restrictions etc. is defined.